# How do I change adapter settings without a mouse?

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Window 7 Professional I’m trying to connect to my WiFi to upgrade it to Windows 10.My mouse arrives two days from now so I’m trying to enable wireless connection without a mouse. Is there any way I can do this by just using a keyboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many windows/dialogs can be manipulated by the keyboard, for example using Tab to move to the next object.

Comment: if all else fails, perhaps powershell? http://woshub.com/powershell-configure-windows-networking/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of way to control network settings through PowerShell, but it’s probably easier to turn on Mouse Keys to simulate a mouse.

This will enable you to move your mouse cursor using the numeric keypad. You can also perform left and right click actions. You should be able to navigate to your control panel using the windows key and cursor keys in conjunction with space and enter to activate items.

Go to “Ease of Access” and then “Make Mouse Easier to use”" and then turn on mouse keys and adjust the settings as suits your needs. Use the Numeric Keypad <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> with the <kbd>5</kbd> key to click or right-click.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tab a lot.

I can't get win-r to work on my test VM, but it should work for you, but you should be able to get the "run" menu up that way.

You can use that to fire up `ncpa.cpl` - and use tab to select the wireless device. Hit enter and you *should* be able to open up the settings for the adaptor. I don't have wireless on my test VM - so I don't have screenshots, but the 'classic' UI was much more friendly to changing settings with tab.

Tab between options, change them as needed, and you're all good I think